# Hazelcast Distributed Lock with iMap

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, distributed, hazelcast

We are currently using Hazelcast 3.1.5.
I have a simple distributed locking mechanism that is supposed to provide thread safety across multiple JVM nodes. Code is pretty simple.

```
 private static HazelcastInstance hInst = getHazelcastInstance();

 private IMap<String, Integer> mapOfLocks = null;
  ...
  ...

   mapOfLocks = hInst.getMap("mapOfLocks");
        if (mapOfLocks.get(name) == null) {
            mapOfLocks.put(name,1);
            mapOfLocks.lock(name);
        }
        else {
            mapOfLocks.put(name,mapOfLocks.get(name)+1);
        }
         ...
         <STUFF HAPPENS HERE>
         mapOfLocks.unlock(name);
         ..
    }
```

Earlier, I used to call HazelcastInstance.getLock() directly and things seemed to work, though we never saw anything out of place when multiple JVMs were involved.
Recently, I was asked to investigate a database deadlock in  block, and after weeks of investigation and log analysis, I was able to determine this was caused by multiple threads being able to acquire the lock against the same key. Before the first thread can commit the  code, second thread manages to get another lock, at which point the second thread is blocked by the Database lock from the first thread.

Is there any outstanding bug against Hazelcast implementation of distributed locks, should I be doing anything differently with my configuration?
And, Oh my configuration has multicast disabled and tcp-ip enabled

Comment: If the value does exists, you're not locking it (at least your code snippet doesn't show this). So you could run into this issue here.
Additionally your code doesn't verify that the map value didn't change, between your check and update. If the map value does matter, it might be better to switch to putIfAbsent and replace(K,V,V).

Answer (score 11):

Here is how you can use IMap as a lock container.
You don't need to have entry for the `name` present in the map in order to lock it.

```
HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
IMap<Object, Object> lockMap = instance.getMap("lockMap");
lockMap.lock(name);
try {
    //do some work
} finally {
    lockMap.unlock(name);
}
```