# How to synchronise hazelcast interaction with the DB psql?

Tags: java, psql, hazelcast

i have 2 instances of my spring boot app and i want to coordinate the database insertion between the two nodes. Is it possible with hazelcast map?

Comment: Do you want to store data in Hazelcast `IMap` alongside database, or do you just want to avoid concurrent access to database?

Comment: to avoid concurrent access to database

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is possible with map. example

```
if(map.get(somekey)==null){
   map.put(somekey,val);
   // do DB stuff
   map.remove(somekey);
}
```

but I highly suggest use Lock from https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Distributed_Data_Structures/index.html. because its safer and logical way. here is lock example usage https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.0/manual/html/ch02s07.html

also check [Hazelcast Distributed Lock with iMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30765727/hazelcast-distributed-lock-with-imap)

Comment: The example is not thread safe, I don't recommend to use it. But you are correct that a distributed lock can be used to coordinate multiple insertions between two nodes.